# Increase SCNParticleSystem.emitterShape detail level

Tags: scenekit, particle-system, vertices

An SCNParticleSystem has a property for the origin of its particles, emitterShaper of type SCNGeometryShape.

There's various choices available in the Scene Editor, from Plane to Sphere, Box and Point. More details on emitterShape in Apple docs [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNParticleSystem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNParticleSystem/emitterShape)

If using a Plane, how do I change the level of detail of that Plane?

The default is a Plane of one polygon, i.e. a square with four vertices. I want a lot more vertices.

Planes have a segment count that can be changed.

I'd like to change the [widthSegmentCount](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPlane_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNPlane/widthSegmentCount) and the [heightSegmentCount](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPlane_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNPlane/heightSegmentCount) of the plane, but been unable to find a way to do this in the Scene Editor.

How do I do this in the Scene Editor (if it's possible) otherwise how to do it with code?

::EDIT::
Here's a Matrix inspired example of one situation where this ability might be very useful:

[image]

Comment: Why do you need more vertex? are you emitting from the vertex?

Comment: Yes, I'm emitting from the vertex. I need much more positions, many more, to create the desired effect. I can make (and have) MANY more particle emitters, but everyone of them increases the draw count, whereas having them all sourced from the one emitter with the ideal number of vertices splayed along its length solves this problem more gracefully, with much better performance.

Comment: Added example image of a scenario where this might be useful...

Comment: if you use the sample particle system emitted from many nodes (i.e share it), it will end up in 1 draw call. Also I don't know if this is applicable in your case but you can emit from the surface of a shape instead of its vertex.

Comment: also if you use xcode, and clone a node with a particle system, the particle system will be shared

Comment: Do you mean if I use "code" and clone it, not the scene editor, then it will be shared? I'm seeing a draw call for each particle system, at the moment.

Comment: No, surface emitting doesn't work, the columns appearance I'm after is not possible because of the randomness of positions for spawn when using surface.